# Очистить буфер ob_start от цифры 1 в начале

Tags: php, ajax, json

```
function esp_search_ajax_action_callback(){

    // if (!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['nonce'], 'search-nonce')){
    //  wp_die('Данные отправлены с левого адреса');
    // }

    $arg = array(
        'post_type' => array('post', 'page'),
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        's' => $_POST['s']
    );
    $query_ajax = new WP_Query($arg);
    $json_data['out'] = ob_start(PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE);
    if ( $query_ajax->have_posts()) {
        while ($query_ajax->have_posts()) {
            $query_ajax->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="title-searche">фывфывфыв</div>
            <?php
               }
    } 
    $json_data['out'] .= ob_get_clean();
    wp_send_json($json_data);
    wp_die();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему при передаче данных в начале появлается цифра 1 и как его удалить?

Comment: 1 - это содержимое поста ($query_ajax->the_post())

Comment: 1 - это результат выполнения ob_start

Comment: При выводе на странице она тоже отображается вместе с постами